# Do my AWS EC2 instances need to move into my VPC when I move our RDS instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

We have an AWS account with multiple EC2 instances and an RDS instance. These have been running since before VPCs were introduced.  Now I need to upgrade the RDS instance class and the new class can only be established in a VPC.  So if our RDS instance is modified (converted) into the new class and the new RDS instance is in a VPC will the EC2 instances that use this RDS need to be moved into the VPC at the same time or can this be a separate process?

Comment: i’m not sure exactly but i _think_ it can be separate so long as you have a way to access the vpc .. for example setup a separate ec2 instance that’s in the vpc but publicly exposed then you can use that ec2 as a proxy ... please don’t take this as an answer though as i am not certain of it working nor more importantly am i certain of any security implications

Comment: I'd expect the process to be: disconnect all clients cleanly, migrate RDS, migrate clients, reconfigure clients, reconnect clients. There's no process by which you can migrate RDS *and* the clients at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RDS and EC2 security groups are not cross-compatible between classic and vpc EC2. If you have an RDS with an EC2 sec group reference you will not be able to add a classic ec2 sec group to your vpc RDS sec group.

[Differences Between Security Groups for EC2-Classic and EC2-VPC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_SecurityGroups.html#VPC_Security_Group_Differences)

Your best bet is to migrate your EC2 infrastructure to VPC along with your RDS. You can of course grant global access to your RDS if you want to separate the process and then lock it back down when you've migrated your EC2 infrastructure but this is a big no no (huge security risk).

This is a non trivial process and I feel your pain. The least complex thing is to incur downtime during migration so that you don't have divergence between RDS instances. But that's not ideal especially when you have a large RDS storage-wise. BTW, you will want to test how long the process takes to snapshot and restore the RDS since it might take a while.

An alternative if you can manage it is to force your app to use read-only replicas while you migrate the RDS. That way your app can still function (kind of) and you won't have to worry about reconciliation between RDS instances post-migration. But obviously your app needs to be aware that it's in read-only mode or you'll end up with erratic behavior.

Forgot to mention there is something called classic-link which might help here but I've personally never used classic-link. Check it out in an AWS whitepaper write up here:

[Move Amazon RDS MySQL
Databases to Amazon VPC
using Amazon EC2
ClassicLink and Read
Replicas](https://d1.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/RDS/Moving_RDS_MySQL_DB_to_VPC.pdf)

Comment: Thanks ekeyser.  This is a good summary of what I found since posting the question.  It appears that ClassicLink may be a good means for converting the RDS now and the ECS instances later... I'm soon to find out.